# Digicart File Transfers

Tags: file-transfer, workflow

This question is for anyone who has experience with 360 Systems' Digicart.

There are some ideas floating around on how we can make use of this nice, expensive, television studio we have at work. We're planning on shooting some test episodes of these ideas, and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to get audio files onto our Digicart (which I've barely used before). We can route audio to it and record to the internal hard drive, but that just seems like a huge time sap to me (which it probably is).

Also, this thing is only about a year and a half/two years old....who the hell still puts ZIP DRIVES in their gear anymore?! lol

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so through various conversations and trial and error the short answer is...no.

In case any of you ever end up working with one of these things, it does appear that the only way to get new sounds in is to record them into the unit. You can transfer files from one Digicart to another over a network...but you still have to record the audio into one to start off...at least for the model we have (Digicart|E).

It's a great piece of gear for doing what it's designed to do, but it is in some serious need of an update!